# how to connect mongodb(cloud) cluster database with python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://new_user_7:new_user_7@cluster0-xsoeo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 622, in __init__
    connect_timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 390, in parse_uri
    raise ConfigurationError('The "dnspython" module must be '
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

python file response and not connect python pymongo

Comment: pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs     |  Please anyone help me..

Comment: The error message seems relatively clear…!?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `dnspython` module.

Try `pip install dnspython` to install it.